# How long will it take for my baby dragon to mature

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, aging

I recently found a baby dragon in the mountains and managed to befriend it and i was wondering how long it would take for it to mature

Comment: @NautArch - can you ask a welcome message? I've lost my draft.